# Gunicorn behavior with worker and thread configuration

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm currently using Gunicorn version 20.1.0, and I have a question regarding the behavior of Gunicorn when using the following command:

Dockerfile

```
 CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers", "20", "--threads", "5", "application:application", "--max-requests", "250", "--max-requests-jitter", "50"]
```

My initial understanding was that this command should instruct Gunicorn to start 20 workers, each supported by 5 threads. After each worker completes 250 requests, it should be terminated and a new worker should be spawned. However, the observed behavior is different.

The number of workers (processes with different PIDs) keeps increasing beyond 60, which eventually leads to memory exhaustion and timeouts. It seems like the workers are not being terminated as expected.

My question is two-fold:

Does Gunicorn create more than 20 workers as I specified in the command?
Is Gunicorn failing to terminate workers that have served 250 requests?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me understand and rectify this behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at two param `max-requests=250` and `max-requests-jitter=50`

When config  `max-requests-jitter=50`, it will keep only `randint(0, max_requests_jitter)` worker will restart on same time. When a mount request spam to server, max 50 worker will restart but now randint worker is only 5 worker restart same time and need some seconds that need to start new worker,  a mount request continous spamming to server so the worker master keep sharing request to another worker (now with 15 worker, in spite of over 250 request but `max-requests-jitter=50` so it can't restart).

After 50 worker restarted. Gunicorn continue retarting another worker

Comment: More detail why it can get only 5 worker restart but not 20, https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#max-requests-jitter

Comment: thanks @TanThie. However, I believe my que remains unanswered. I get how max-requests-jitter works it randomly selects a number and subtracts it from max-requests, causing the worker to restart after serving requests. For e.g, if the jitter were set to 30, the worker would restart after processing between 220 and 250 requests.

Comment: My concern is abt the persistence of old workers, that continue to show as alive.  let's say I have 10 workers, and they have all been replaced by new 10 workers. In such a situation, I would expect to see only 10 PIDs associated with the currently active workers, not 15 or more. The presence of additional PIDs suggests that some old workers are still alive, and I'm trying to understand why this might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation `—threads` only “affects the Gthread worker type.” A sync worker will become a gthread woker (when and if threads is set above 1). So, your configuration sets up 20 gthread workers each with 5 threads.
By using `max-requests-jitters` you are allowing an extra delay before gunicorn restarts an exhausted worker (i.e one that has run 250 requests), which means more than 20 workers could be running at any one moment (more as the random jitter increases). As a side note, keep in mind the rough formula for the number of synchronous workers is: 2-4 * #number of cores. And, the suggested maximum concurrent requests when using workers and threads is (2*CPU)+1. So, 20 workers with 5 threads each could be too high, unless you’re expecting 100+ simultaneous requests and have the hardware to handle it.

Comment: thanks for your message Gregory, yes, pretty much aware of all those things, one question to clarify what you mentioned about max-requites-jitters, as per my understanding a worker will be marked for shutdown once it crosses 250-random number based on jitters, i.e if a random number is 20 then anytime after it crosses 230 requests, but are you suggesting that's not the case? and it will be still used after 250 requests? 
BTW, found out it was due to boto3 used for aws resources not closing connections, so the combination of closing them and not using max req at all might do the job, in test..

Comment: okay running the top command shows that most of the workers are sleeping 

```Tasks:  59 total,   1 running,  58 sleeping```

Comment: Yes, if your max request is 250 and random jitter max is 50, each worker will be marked for shutdown between 250-300 requests (250 + 0-50).  So, worker1 could be 262, worker2 could be 280, worker3 could be 299, etc.

Comment: okay thanks, ChatGPT thinks otherwise :-) 

```For example, if you set --max-requests to 200 and --max-requests-jitter to 50, a worker might restart anywhere between 150 and 200 requests. This randomization helps distribute the restarts more evenly, leading to smoother performance.```

Comment: 'think' what it might, I'd trust the documentation: "The maximum jitter to *add* to the max_requests setting."  https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#settings

Answer (score 0):

okay turned out to be an issue with a couple of things

1. the boto3 with aws resources were not closed.
2. some lib function usedfor timeout
3. the max-request and jitter

we still see a rise in memory but very slow, but the workers are now constant